# How to group mysql data by unique data range

Tags: mysql

I want to create a sql query for this right side output from left side data, as shown in the image below:

[image]

This is the query I have so far, but it isn't getting the correct results:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(Date),?Last day of month,YEAR(date)) AS Date,
       SUM(Amount1) AS rslt1,
       SUM(Amount2) AS rslt2 
FROM table 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
```

Comment: It's quite an interesting requirement, and I am sure if you put your attempted  query in your question then you would get some good answers

Comment: Thank you your valuble idea. This is my attempted query. But It's now work

`SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(Date),?Last day of month,YEAR(date)) AS Date, SUM(Amount1) AS rslt1, SUM(Amount2) AS rslt2 FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(date),YEAR(date)`

Comment: I have made some edits to your question to help improve, but if possible, can you provide the results that you are currently getting from that query. So we can see what exactly is wrong with the results

Comment: So, why the 30th?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example...

```
SELECT ym
     , @a1 := @a1 + a1 amount1
     , @a2 := @a2 + a2 amount2
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym 
            , SUM(amount1) a1
            , SUM(amount2) a2 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY ym 
     ) x
     , (SELECT @a1:=0,@a2:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY ym;
```